# How to change width of Thunar menu width

Tags: xfce, thunar

I'm using Thunar with XFCE4 and I found a problem. The sub-menu "Create Document" can't be fully displayed (the sub-menu is too narrow, just as the picture shows), but other sub-menus are OK. How can I fix it please? [create document sub-menu can't be displayed correctly]

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a GTK bug - reverting gtk3 resolves the issue. More information in the upstream bug report: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15200

Comment: Thanks for your help! Reverting gtk3 to version 3.24.5 solved my problem!